# SQL: If there are two rows that contain same record, want it to display one

Tags: sql, sql-server

based on my question above, below is the SQL

```
SELECT ets_tools.tools_id, ets_borrower.fullname, ets_team.team_name, ets_borrow.time_from, 
ets_borrow.time_to, ets_borrow.borrow_id FROM ets_tools 
INNER JOIN ets_tools_borrow ON ets_tools.tools_id = ets_tools_borrow.tools_id 
INNER JOIN ets_borrow ON ets_borrow.borrow_id = ets_tools_borrow.borrow_id 
INNER JOIN ets_borrower ON ets_borrower.badgeid = ets_borrow.badgeid 
INNER JOIN ets_team ON ets_team.team_id = ets_borrower.team_id 
WHERE ets_tools.borrow_id IS NOT NULL AND ets_borrow.status_id = 1 AND ets_borrow.time_to IS NULL
```

and the result display like this:

[image]

From the image above, we can see that the borrow_id with value 1 display two rows. Now, how to display only one borrow_id for value 1 since its duplicate the same things.

Anyone can help?

Comment: You can also use ROW_NUMBER() and only select R=1 rows (or DELETE anything R>1 to de-dupe)
Also look into why you have duplicate data in the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to retain the record having the *smallest* `tools_id`, you could aggregate by the other columns and take the `MIN` of `tools_id`:

```
SELECT
    MIN(ets_tools.tools_id) AS tools_id,
    ets_borrower.fullname,
    ets_team.team_name,
    ets_borrow.time_from,
    ets_borrow.time_to,
    ets_borrow.borrow_id
FROM ets_tools 
INNER JOIN ets_tools_borrow ON ets_tools.tools_id = ets_tools_borrow.tools_id 
INNER JOIN ets_borrow ON ets_borrow.borrow_id = ets_tools_borrow.borrow_id 
INNER JOIN ets_borrower ON ets_borrower.badgeid = ets_borrow.badgeid 
INNER JOIN ets_team ON ets_team.team_id = ets_borrower.team_id 
WHERE
    ets_tools.borrow_id IS NOT NULL AND
    ets_borrow.status_id = 1 AND
    ets_borrow.time_to IS NULL
GROUP BY
    ets_borrower.fullname,
    ets_team.team_name,
    ets_borrow.time_from,
    ets_borrow.time_to,
    ets_borrow.borrow_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change the `SELECT` to `SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES`

And at the end add `ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ets_borrow.borrow_id ORDER BY ets_tools.tools_id)`